# What Value to Initialize Non-NULL Pointer to?

Tags: c, pointers

If I want to get a value for `endptr` in [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/), I need to pass in a non-NULL pointer. What value should I initialise a temporary `end` pointer to, without doing something ugly like this?

```
char x = '0';
char *y = &x;
char **end = &y;
long l = strtol (str, end, base);
```

Comment: Passing a `NULL` pointer means doing `strtol("42", NULL, 10)`; passing the address of a variable (whatever it contains) **is not** passing a `NULL` pointer

Comment: Does not matter what you set it to.  Did you look at the example code for the link you reference?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps like this:

```
char *end;
long l = strtol (str, &end, base);
```

It is the *address* of `end` which is passed, not its value, so `NULL` is not passed.

*If endptr is not NULL, a pointer to the character that stopped the scan is stored at the location pointed to by endptr. If no conversion can be performed (no valid digits were found or an invalid base was specified), the value of strSource is stored at the location pointed to by endptr.*

Comment: If you really like initializing things, you can even do `char *end = NULL;`, and `&end` will still be non-NULL.